# After deploying UGC on presentation website arabic encoding not working

Tags: ugc

I am using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2. After deploying the changes for UGC with all its jars and xml changes, arabic text entered from any form on the website returns junk characters. The website worked perfectly uptil the release. We can see all data entered into DB properly but now the form submit returns junk characters
In web.xml, I commented this filter-mapping

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After this I can see the arabic text submitted by form in the logs and saved to DB. But I get a nullpointer exception when I call syncUGCUserWithContact at these lines

> claimStore.put(URI.create("taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:user"),
>   ugcUser.getId());

and

> claimStore.contains(BasePostClaimProcessor.USER_CLAIM)

What should I put in url pattern exception so that I don't get this exception?
Also, my UGC content on which I need to add comment doensn't load for logged in users

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>       com.tridion.ugc.taglib.webservice.WebServiceHelper.getUserId(WebServiceHelper.java:183)
>     at
>   com.tridion.ugc.taglib.ManageCommentsTag.doStartTag(ManageCommentsTag.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.data.pub10.dcp.jsp.dcp12075_005f13053_jsp._jspService(dcp12075_005f13053_jsp.java:359)

**UPDATE:11/06/2014**
Ok. I will keep the /*. But i don't understand how removing this pattern affected arabic form submission. I read in this article by Eric [enter link description here](http://erichuiza.blogspot.com/2012/07/ambient-data-framework-in-nutshell.html) that

> Being technology agnostic ADF cannot access to technology specific
>   objects like HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse or HttpContext,
>   that is why we need a java filter or a .Net Http Module to start it.

Also I have added this is in cd_ambient_conf.xml. Should I add any other path here?

```
<ExcludedPaths>
        <Path>/httpupload</Path>
        <Path>/odata.svc</Path>
    </ExcludedPaths>
```

Please help. This problem is on live website

Comment: It could be that your character encoding might not have setup correctly - should be UTF-8 or whatever appropriate. Take a look at : http://elenaserghie.blogspot.com/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Comment: If you still have the same problem after following Elena's clues, consider sharing what is in the database and how your web site retrieves the information from the database.

Comment: I checked the UTF-8 on all xml files. Its there.In the web.xmll file, I commented the below pattern <!--Uncomment the following block to apply the filter for the UGC user. Url-pattern "/*" should be replaced with the adequate one.
    --> 
    <!--<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Ambient Data Framework</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern></filter-mapping>
    -->  After commenting this I can see that my form submits the arabic text but in my SyncUGCUserWithContact class it throws NPE at claimStore.put(URI.create("taf:claim:contentdelivery:webservice:user"), ugcUser.getId());

Comment: @Rache it is better to edit your question in answer to comments, that way you have decent formatting features available to make your question more readable and clear to everybody.

Comment: Hi Rache, can you also clarify what version of Tridion you are having this issue on?

Comment: The exception is caused by the code accessing the ADF, but you just commented that out so the ADF isn't available. It's not related to the original problem, except for the fact that your troubleshooting caused a new issue :)

Comment: The community is pretty quick to respond (notice the same-day answers) but for urgent ("live") issues I would always follow-up with a Support ticket. :-) Btw, were you able to solve this??